How can I refetch a query conditionally with TRPC + react query?
In my next js 14 App I am using TRPC + react query to fetch data from my server.
I have a component that shows the count of notifications:
export function BadgedUserAvatar(): JSX.Element {

//Fetch the notifications count
  const { data: count } = trpc.inbox.count.useQuery();

  return (
    <Badge
      badgeContent={count}
      color="warning"
      invisible={isProfileComplete()}
      overlap="circular"
    >
      ...
    </Badge>
  );
}

On another component I fetch the list of notifications and can also mark them as read. If I mark them as read I refetch the notifications list to update the UI:
export default function Inbox(): JSX.Element {
...
  const { data, isLoading, refetch } = trpc.inbox.search.useQuery({
    query: { offset: 0, limit: 5, status: InboxMessageStatus.UNREAD },
  });

  const { mutate: readNotification } = trpc.inbox.read.useMutation({
    onSuccess: () => refetch(),
  });
...
}

The problem is that I don't know how to trigger a refetch on the notifications count when I mark a notification as read. The notifications count is in a separate component and I should fetch that data at first load and then refetch it on every trpc.inbox.read mutation onSuccess

I'm here because of react-query tag, so only a comment: Can you do this in tRPC in Next? https://trpc.io/docs/v9/invalidateQueries
